# Want to Decode the Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, decode

I'm trying to decoding the encoded JavaScript code.

I was having the original code a long time ago and now I need the original code for edits.

Here is my encoded code:

```
var _0xc8e2=["\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x65\x64\x20\x7A\x6F\x6F\x6D\x49\x6E","\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73","\x23\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x76\x61\x6C","\x23\x75\x73\x6E\x61\x6D\x65","\x50\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x20\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x20\x61\x20\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x55\x73\x65\x72\x20\x49\x44","\x31\x30\x30\x25","\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x65","\x23\x70\x72\x6F\x67\x72\x65\x73\x73\x62\x61\x72\x78","\x6F\x70\x61\x63\x69\x74\x79","\x63\x73\x73","\x23\x73\x74\x61\x74\x75\x73\x68\x6F\x6C\x64\x65\x72","\x66\x61\x64\x65\x4F\x75\x74","\x23\x75\x73\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x6D\x65","\x66\x61\x64\x65\x49\x6E","\x23\x72\x65\x73\x6F\x75\x72\x63\x65\x73","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x23\x75\x73\x6C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E"];$(document)[_0xc8e2[3]](function (){$(_0xc8e2[2])[_0xc8e2[1]](_0xc8e2[0]);;;} );$(document)[_0xc8e2[3]](function (){$(_0xc8e2[19])[_0xc8e2[18]](function (){if($(_0xc8e2[6])[_0xc8e2[5]]()[_0xc8e2[4]]<3){alert(_0xc8e2[7]);} else {$(_0xc8e2[15])[_0xc8e2[14]](500,function (){$(_0xc8e2[10])[_0xc8e2[9]]({width:_0xc8e2[8]},10000);setTimeout(function (){$(_0xc8e2[13])[_0xc8e2[12]](_0xc8e2[11],1);} ,10000);} );setTimeout(function (){$(_0xc8e2[17])[_0xc8e2[16]](500);} ,12000);} ;} );} );
```

Comment: Hi. This question is not good. Stack Overflow is not a code deobfuscation service.

Comment: Hello, I know but I am asking for any method or any suggestions that how can I do it.

Comment: Did you try googling _javascript deobfuscate_?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks I will do that an let you know thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is you Ans:
Use: http://www.jspretty.com/ this is better I think

```
$(document)['ready'](function () {
    $('#container')['addClass']('animated zoomIn');;;
});
$(document)['ready'](function () {
    $('#uslogin')['click'](function () {
        if ($('#usname')['val']()['length'] < 3) {
            alert('Please enter a valid User ID');
        } else {
            $('#username')['fadeOut'](500, function () {
                $('#progressbarx')['animate']({
                    width: '100%'
                }, 10000);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#statusholder')['css']('opacity', 1);
                }, 10000);
            });
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#resources')['fadeIn'](500);
            }, 12000);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay I will check this and let you know if this is my answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
var _0xc8e2 = ["animated zoomIn", "addClass", "#container", "ready", "length", "val", "#usname", "Please enter a valid User ID", "100%", "animate", "#progressbarx", "opacity", "css", "#statusholder", "fadeOut", "#username", "fadeIn", "#resources", "click", "#uslogin"];
$(document)[_0xc8e2[3]](function() {
    $(_0xc8e2[2])[_0xc8e2[1]](_0xc8e2[0]);;;
});
$(document)[_0xc8e2[3]](function() {
    $(_0xc8e2[19])[_0xc8e2[18]](function() {
        if ($(_0xc8e2[6])[_0xc8e2[5]]()[_0xc8e2[4]] < 3) {
            alert(_0xc8e2[7]);
        } else {
            $(_0xc8e2[15])[_0xc8e2[14]](500, function() {
                $(_0xc8e2[10])[_0xc8e2[9]]({
                    width: _0xc8e2[8]
                }, 10000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(_0xc8e2[13])[_0xc8e2[12]](_0xc8e2[11], 1);
                }, 10000);
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(_0xc8e2[17])[_0xc8e2[16]](500);
            }, 12000);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: How did you do that ?

Comment: He used jsbeautify.org